# Incrementing the number is not working in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have the following function in my counter.js file:

```
//counter.js
var counter = 1;

function increment() {
  counter++;
}

function decrement() {
  counter--;
}

function getCounter() {
  return counter;
}

module.exports = {
  counter: counter,
  increment: increment,
  decrement: decrement,
  getCounter: getCounter
};
```

In my main.js, I have the following code:

```
//main.js
var counter = require('./counter');
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.counter); // 1
console.log(counter.getCounter()); // 2
```

I am unable to understand, why does the

> counter.counter

gives 1 as output, whereas the

> counter.getCounter()

gives 2 as the output.
What is the possible explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the possible explanation for this behavior?

JavaScript is pass/call/assign **by value** (and no, people who claim objects are passed *by* reference [are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/218196)). That means when you did

```
module.exports = {
  counter: counter,
  ...
};
```

a *copy* of the *current* value of the `counter` variable (i.e. the value `counter` has at the moment that line is executed) is assigned to the `counter` property. Subsequently changing the value of the *variable* `counter` has no effect on the *property* `counter`.

Here is a simpler example of the situation:

```js
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
foo = 21;
console.log(bar); // still 42, not 21
```

---

`getCounter()` on the other hand reads the value of the variable `counter` every time it is called, so it will always return the current value of the variable.

Comment: Agreed naturally. Noting that a possible point of the OP's confusion may well be assuming the "module" is in the context of an "object" re: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/2313887). Which of course a "module" is not.

Answer (score 0):

Felix, of course, above has great explanation why this works the way it does. A nice solution to the problem (if you don't need to support old js) is to assign a `getter` on your export:

```
module.exports = {
    get counter() { return counter },
    increment: increment,
    decrement: decrement,
};
```

Now when you access `counter.counter` in your other script you'll really be calling a function that grabs the value of `counter` from your module.